# MS Access Code Signing In Access 2016

Tags: code-signing, ms-access-2016

When I Digitally sign a MS Access Database(2007-2016), it creates a signed package. That's great but when it is sent to a client, they open it up, prompting to save the accdb file.

Is this accdb signed in any way? 
It does not show anywhere that the code has been signed by me.

What am I missing?